# How to remove Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: software-center

I recently updated 13.04, and upgraded the kernel. After that, the software center seems not to be working. when I click on the icon, the logo just blinks and nothing happens. Is it possible to correct this, or how do I remove the software center.

When I issue the command

```
sudo apt-get remove software-center
```

it, asks to remove `ubuntu-desktop` too. What is ubuntu-desktop, and is it very important for the system ?

Comment: Ubuntu-desktop requires the software center to be installed. I do not believe it is possible to remove the software center without removing ubuntu-desktop.

Comment: Is the ubuntu-desktop really important. I know it is important for updating the sysmtem.

Comment: First search **Dash** for **`Software Center`**. Does that icon work? It may just be the icon docked (leftover, from before upgrade).

Comment: No, none of the icons work

Comment: Please read this link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto. In general, many of your doubts will be clarified if you visit help.ubuntu.com.

Comment: Also please search askubuntu.com for what "ubuntu-desktop" is about and its significance.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 sudo apt-get -f update
 sudo apt-get -f upgrade
```

just to fix any existing problems. Then

```
 sudo apt-get --reinstall install software-center
```

to re-install software center.

Comment: What doe the apt-get do ?

Comment: @RoshanGeorge `apt-get` is a command line package management tool.

Comment: i know that, but, what does --reinstall install does?

Comment: `apt-get` is a command line tool to fetch software from repositories along with any other required software (dependencies) and install them on your computer. `-f` says "fix". `update` updates the list of software with updates available, `upgrade` upgrades those those updates. `install` installs, `--reinstall` says "reinstall" something that's already  installed.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a more advanced alternative to the software center you can install synaptic by typing sudo apt-get install synaptic

Answer (score -2):

Firstly Don't remove software center because it is of great use.

Secondly:rather installing from software center install the packages from Terminal using
"apt-get install package_name"
"apt-fast install package_name"

before using apt-fast you need to install it by typing

"apt-get install apt-fast"

using apt-fast increases the downloading speed of your install

Comment: I get the following errors when adding the repos..
 [link](http://pastebin.com/Atnq478Y)